# Html layout and have the body content extend past the set width and remain on same line

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have a layout with header, footer, body content.  It is a pretty standard layout.  We have reports that sometimes extend past the hard coded width'  But we need the left nav and the body content to the same line.  With this HTML code below, if the width extends too far (say there is a content in the body that has more than 900+ width) then the body content flows below the left nav.

Basically, we want the content and left nav to remain on the same row regardless how much content is actually in that body content section.  Is there a way to force the browser to keep those to items on the same row ALWAYS.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #bodyFull {

            }

            #header {
                border: 3px solid #f00;
                background-color: #99F;
                width: 900px;
            }

            #footer {

                border: 3px solid #909;
                background-color: #F99;
                width: 900px;

            }

            #leftNav {
                float: left;
                width: 150px;
                height: 800px;
                border: 2px solid #777;
                background-color: #FF9;
            }

            #bodyContent {
                float: left;

                border: 2px solid #707;
                background-color: #AAA;

                width: 1024px;
                height: 1024px;
                            overflow: hidden

            }

            #mainBody {

                width: 920px;
            }


        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="bodyFull">

            <div id="header">
                The Header
            </div>

            <div id="mainBody">

                <div id="leftNav">
                    Left Nav
                </div>

                <div id="bodyContent">
                    The Body
                </div>

                The End of Main Body

            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div id="footer">
                The Footer
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Small typo:  bodyContent to rest at the same row as the leftNav.

/* !!! CAN THIS SECTION REMAIN ON THE SAME ROW AS THE LEFT Nav, EVEN THOUGH IT EXTENDS PAST THE 'HEADER/BODYFULL' width
                     */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, forget my `margin-left` suggestion, misunderstood the problem. If you want to make sure that div is always, say, 750px (so that plus the left nav is the same width as the header) then set its width to 750px and set either `overflow: auto` to add a scrollbar on that part of the page where necessary, or `overflow: hidden` to just truncate it.

Comment: Closer, but I did make a small typo

For example, if you copy paste the code above and try this in IE.  the body is sitting below the left nav, is there a way to avoid this.

Comment: If you change #bodyContent's width to 750px and overflow is auto or hidden as I said here, and #leftNav is still 150px, and #mainBody is still 920px, then #leftNav and #bodyContent should be on the same line because they fit in their containing block. Do those changes not work?

Answer (score 0):

Scratch what I said before, I misunderstood you.  Try out the code below and let me know if it is what you are looking for.  Otherwise you are going to need be more specific what you need.  However you might want to check out this [liquid layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm) and then put a wrapper div around it with a set width.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">

            #bodyFull {
            }

            #header {
                    border: 3px solid #f00;
                    background-color: #99F;
                    width: 900px;
            }

            #footer {

                    border: 3px solid #909;
                    background-color: #F99;
                    width: 900px;

            }

            #leftNav {
                    float: left;
                    width: 150px;
                    height: 800px;
                    border: 2px solid #777;
                    background-color: #FF9;
            }

            #bodyContent {
                    float: left;
                    border: 2px solid #707;
                    background-color: #AAA;
                                            width:748px;
                    height: 1024px;
                                            overfloat:auto;
            }

            #mainBody {
                                            width:906px;
                                            overfloat: auto;
            }


    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="bodyFull">

            <div id="header">
                    The Header
            </div>

            <div id="mainBody">

                    <div id="leftNav">
                            Left Nav
                    </div>

                    <div id="bodyContent">
                            The Body
                    </div>

                    The End of Main Body

            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div id="footer">
                    The Footer
            </div>

    </div>

</body>
```